# Windows10 Chrome изменились шрифты, emoji черно-белые

Tags: шрифты

Установил какую-то сомнительную программу и теперь в chrome, opera, yandex шрифт стал другим + emoji стали черно-белыми. Очень неудобно, хочу вернуть всё как было. На firefox шрифт остался прежний и emoji цветные. Помогите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чисто как вариант можно удалить программу и все станет на свои места

Comment: Не помогло.....

Comment: а если хром переустановить и мозиллу тоже, может проблема в них?

Comment: Тоже не помогло.

Comment: вы хотя бы знаете что именно вы установили?)

Comment: Какой-то кряк для игры. Тема актуальна.

Comment: то есть все-таки такая проблема осталась даже после того что вы делали... хм... это довольно странно, ведь если вы снесли кряк, то должно все подчиститься, хотя может кряк себе что-то еще наставил дополнительно? вы не смотрели может что-то еще поставилось кроме кряка?